rnmapbox-maps/rnmapbox_maps.modulemap' not found
During the compilation process, it's getting this error:
It's not using Expo.

/Users/USER-NAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT-ID/Build/Intermediates.noindex/project.build/Debug-iphoneos/project.build/DerivedSources/project_vers.c module map file '/Users/USER-NAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT-ID/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/rnmapbox-maps/rnmapbox_maps.modulemap' not found

This project is built without problems on another machine, both M1.
